# Paypal integration with spree 3.2.0 rc1 or spree 3.0+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway, spree, spree-paypal-express

E-commerce website with spreecommerce and Rails 5.0.1. Application included following gems.

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
```

Spree Paypal Express will not work with `spree 3.0+` https://github.com/spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express and they recommended to use Braintree v.zero extension.

Try to use https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero but braintree currently not supporting India Region.
Which gem can i use for paypal integration. How can i integrate Paypal with rails and spreecommerce as express checkout.

If apart from Paypal any other payment service that work on USA, UK, Japan, India and easy to integrate with spree and rails is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Spree paypal rest works fine

https://github.com/hugomarquez/spree_paypal_rest

or you can use my fork (small fixes concerning https - not needed if your shop is not running on https)
https://github.com/pavels/spree_paypal_rest/network

Comment: if https://github.com/pavels/spree_paypal_rest/network work well with https, i'll try it and ping if found any issue or working fine. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2709290/pigster spree_paypal_rest (= 1.0.2) was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on  rails (~> 4.2.7), can you update your gem and released it for Rails 5.0+